# jQuery callbacks - short version

Tags: jquery

I've dug the manual and tried extensivelly to drop the extra `function(){...}` call after the `error` and `success` to do it like mootools but to no good luck.

Is there any way i can avoid the extra `function` in jQuery?

```
function doFileDelete(ui) {
    $.ajax({
        error: function() { doFileDeleteAnimation(ui, false) },
        success: function() { doFileDeleteAnimation(ui, true) },
        url: '/url-to-delete-file'
    });
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got there? It seems like fairly idiomatic javascript to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no arguments in the function you would like to call, yes, you can just pass the name of the function as your parameter for your callback. However, if you have at least one argument, you must declare the function and pass the necessary data.

Read more in the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Callback_and_Functions) regarding callbacks.

Comment: Thanks Jason! I've dug into the API and missed all the how-to's. I find jQuery's manual, so far, a bit sparser than the moo one. Nevertheless thank you for the great advice.

Comment: Very useful! Already printed and sitting above my screen! Thank you very much!

Comment: it's actually my comp's wallpaper :) glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

You could also eliminate that outer function by using [`Function.prototype.bind`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind) (either the Prototype library version or the ECMAScript 5 native version if your browser supports it). For example:

```
function handler(myBoolean) {
  console.log(myBoolean); // will output true
}

$(function() {
  $('#test').click(handler.bind(this, true));
});
```

The first argument to `bind` is the context you want to execute the function within. Subsequent parameters are passed to the `handler` function. When jQuery executes `handler` as a callback, the function calls are curried and the parameters it passes will be tacked onto the ones you specified in your `bind` call. So, in my example `handler` would receive three parameters when you click on `#test`: the boolean you passed in, the event object, and the DOM element that was clicked.

jQuery has a rough equivalent of `bind` with its function [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/). By default, it doesn't allow you to curry functions like `bind` does, but someone [wrote an extension to it](http://azoffdesign.com/plugins/js/jquery-proxy) that will give it that functionality.

In my opinion, `bind` is a better choice than `$.proxy` since it has cleaner syntax, doesn't require you to monkey patch jQuery, and will be supported natively by browsers once ECMAScript 5 is fully implemented.

Comment: Thank you! This will sure be a nice workaround to some of the more complex part of the program I'll have to dwell into latter!